# Shorthand Directory Paths in Codes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby

i know this may be a simple question but your advise would be much appreciated.

I've never fully understood shorthand directory. Looking at the image;

> **QUESTION**

- Could one explain what `../../hoc/Aux` refers to. In the
  `BurgerBuilder.js` file - Is this referring to, existing out onto the folder
  `'BurgerBuilder'`, then existing out onto the `'containers'` folder, then
  existing out onto the `'src'` folder? should this then be
  `.../../hoc/Aux` with 3 dots, instead of `../../hoc/Aux`?
- And what does the 2 dots `..**/../**hoc/Aux` **in-between** refer to? looking at
  the image, is this referring to **skipping** the `'components'` and
  `'containers'` folder to get to the `'hoc'` folder?

[image]

I know it's a simple question which i am yet to understand so if you kindly direct me to the right source to learn more would appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just work through it step by step.

```
// Path of burger file
src/containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder.js

// ../
src/containers/BurgerBuilder/

// ../../
src/containers/

// ../../hoc
src/containers/hoc

// ../../Aux
src/containers/hoc/Aux.js
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! That was very helpful